# How to use the Z format specifier in Microsoft's printf (and wprintf)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unicode, printf

I would like to use the `Z` conversion specifier in printf, which is a Microsoft extension as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions

> When the address of an ANSI_STRING or UNICODE_STRING structure is
> passed as the argument, display the string contained in the buffer
> pointed to by the Buffer field of the structure. Use a size modifier
> prefix of w to specify a UNICODE_STRING argument—for example, %wZ. The
> Length field of the structure must be set to the length, in bytes, of
> the string. The MaximumLength field of the structure must be set to
> the length, in bytes, of the buffer.

My code (I use `GetProcAddress` here so that it can be tested without installing the Windows DDK):

```
typedef struct _STRING {
    unsigned short lengthInBytes;
    unsigned short capacityInBytes;
    char* data;
} ANSI_STRING;

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
    unsigned short lengthInBytes;
    unsigned short capacityInBytes;
    wchar_t* data;
} UNICODE_STRING;

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hModule = LoadLibraryW( L"NtosKrnl.exe" );

    typedef void ( CALLBACK *RtlInitAnsiStringType )( ANSI_STRING*, char const* );
    RtlInitAnsiStringType RtlInitAnsiString = ( RtlInitAnsiStringType ) GetProcAddress( hModule, "RtlInitAnsiString" );
    ANSI_STRING ansi_string;
    RtlInitAnsiString( &ansi_string, "Text" );
    errno = 0;
    int Z_a_return = printf( "printf %%Z <= ansi_string: %Z.\n", &ansi_string );
    int Z_a_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", Z_a_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", Z_a_return, Z_a_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int hZ_a_return = printf( "printf %%hZ <= ansi_string: %hZ.\n", &ansi_string );
    int hZ_a_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", hZ_a_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", hZ_a_return, hZ_a_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int wZ_a_return = printf( "printf %%wZ <= ansi_string: %wZ.\n", &ansi_string );
    int wZ_a_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", wZ_a_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", wZ_a_return, wZ_a_errno );

    errno = 0;
    int w_Z_a_return = wprintf( L"wprintf %%Z <= ansi_string: %Z.\n", &ansi_string );
    int w_Z_a_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", w_Z_a_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", w_Z_a_return, w_Z_a_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int w_hZ_a_return = wprintf( L"wprintf %%hZ <= ansi_string: %hZ.\n", &ansi_string );
    int w_hZ_a_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", w_hZ_a_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", w_hZ_a_return, w_hZ_a_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int w_wZ_a_return = wprintf( L"wprintf %%wZ <= ansi_string: %wZ.\n", &ansi_string );
    int w_wZ_a_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", w_wZ_a_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", w_wZ_a_return, w_wZ_a_errno );

    typedef void ( CALLBACK *RtlInitUnicodeStringType )( UNICODE_STRING*, wchar_t const* );
    RtlInitUnicodeStringType RtlInitUnicodeString = ( RtlInitUnicodeStringType ) GetProcAddress( hModule, "RtlInitUnicodeString" );
    UNICODE_STRING unicode_string;
    RtlInitUnicodeString( &unicode_string, L"Text" );
    errno = 0;
    int Z_u_return = printf( "printf %%Z <= unicode_string: %Z.\n", &unicode_string );
    int Z_u_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", Z_u_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", Z_u_return, Z_u_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int hZ_u_return = printf( "printf %%hZ <= unicode_string: %hZ.\n", &unicode_string );
    int hZ_u_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", hZ_u_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", hZ_u_return, hZ_u_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int wZ_u_return = printf( "printf %%wZ <= unicode_string: %wZ.\n", &unicode_string );
    int wZ_u_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", wZ_u_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", wZ_u_return, wZ_u_errno );

    errno = 0;
    int w_Z_u_return = wprintf( L"wprintf %%Z <= unicode_string: %Z.\n", &unicode_string );
    int w_Z_u_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", w_Z_u_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", w_Z_u_return, w_Z_u_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int w_hZ_u_return = wprintf( L"wprintf %%hZ <= unicode_string: %hZ.\n", &unicode_string );
    int w_hZ_u_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", w_hZ_u_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", w_hZ_u_return, w_hZ_u_errno );
    errno = 0;
    int w_wZ_u_return = wprintf( L"wprintf %%wZ <= unicode_string: %wZ.\n", &unicode_string );
    int w_wZ_u_errno = errno;
    printf( "%sprintf returned %d, errno = %d.\n\n", w_wZ_u_return < 0  ?  "\n"  :  "", w_wZ_u_return, w_wZ_u_errno );

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
printf %Z <= ansi_string: 
printf returned -1, errno = 42.

printf %hZ <= ansi_string: Text.
printf returned 33, errno = 0.

printf %wZ <= ansi_string: 
printf returned -1, errno = 42.

wprintf %Z <= ansi_string: Text.
printf returned 33, errno = 0.

wprintf %hZ <= ansi_string: Text.
printf returned 34, errno = 0.

wprintf %wZ <= ansi_string: ??.
printf returned 32, errno = 0.

printf %Z <= unicode_string: Text.
printf returned 35, errno = 0.

printf %hZ <= unicode_string: T e x t .
printf returned 40, errno = 0.

printf %wZ <= unicode_string: Text.
printf returned 36, errno = 0.

wprintf %Z <= unicode_string: T
printf returned -1, errno = 0.

wprintf %hZ <= unicode_string: T
printf returned -1, errno = 0.

wprintf %wZ <= unicode_string: Text.
printf returned 37, errno = 0.
```

A tabular summary:

```
printf  | %Z  | ANSI_STRING    | Bad  | errno == EILSEQ
printf  | %hZ | ANSI_STRING    | Good |
printf  | %wZ | ANSI_STRING    | Bad  | errno == EILSEQ
wprintf | %Z  | ANSI_STRING    | Good |
wprintf | %hZ | ANSI_STRING    | Good |
wprintf | %wZ | ANSI_STRING    | Bad  | output == "??"
printf  | %Z  | UNICODE_STRING | Good |
printf  | %hZ | UNICODE_STRING | Bad  | output == "T e x t "
printf  | %wZ | UNICODE_STRING | Good |
wprintf | %Z  | UNICODE_STRING | Bad  | output == "T"
wprintf | %hZ | UNICODE_STRING | Bad  | output == "T"
wprintf | %wZ | UNICODE_STRING | Good |
```

Conclusion:

`hZ` means `ANSI_STRING`, `wZ` means `UNICODE_STRING` both in `printf` and `wprintf`, while `Z` stands for `UNICODE_STRING` in `printf` and `ANSI_STRING` in `wprintf`.

My problem:

According to the documentation, `Z` means that the argument is the address of an `ANSI_STRING`, and `wZ` means that the argument is the address of a `UNICODE_STRING`, however, my example contradicts this, the meaning of `Z` depends on the function, it is `UNICODE_STRING` in `printf` and `ANSI_STRING` in `wprintf`.

What is wrong with my code? (Or did I misunderstand the documentation?)

**Update**

I reread the documentation, and it has been changed a few days ago, now it says this:

> VS 2013 and earlier
>
> When the address of an ANSI_STRING or UNICODE_STRING structure is
> passed as the argument, display the string contained in the buffer
> pointed to by the Buffer field of the structure. Use a size modifier
> prefix of w to specify a UNICODE_STRING argument—for example, %wZ. The
> Length field of the structure must be set to the length, in bytes, of
> the string. The MaximumLength field of the structure must be set to
> the length, in bytes, of the buffer.
>
> Universal C Runtime (UCRT)
>
> There is a known issue in the UCRT that is currently maintained for
> compatibility. Like the S specifier, the Z specifier without a size
> modifier prefix refers to a UNICODE_STRING when using a narrow
> printing function (like printf) and an ANSI_STRING when using a wide
> printing function (like wprintf). Instead of Z, use hZ to specify an
> ANSI_STRING. wZ (or lZ) can still be used to specify a UNICODE_STRING.

However, the documentation does not provide any practical advice on how to deal with this inconsistency.

If I use a statically linked library, how can I detect the CRT version at compile time?

If I use a dinamically linked library, how can I detect the CRT version at run time?

How can I choose between the above programmatically (e.g. with a macro)?

Comment: Microsoft told you exactly what to do, didn't they?  Use `%hZ` to print ANSI_STRINGs, use `%wZ` to print UNICODE_STRINGs, don't use `%Z`.  Or is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: @zwol: If I cannot influence the format string, and it contains a `Z`, and I have to provide the argument either as an `ANSI_STRING` or as a `UNICODE_STRING`, how can I decide, which one to supply? If it is the old version, it should be the first, if the new version, then the latter. But how do I detect the version?

Comment: `swprintf_s` and `sprintf_s`, `_vsnwprintf`, ... ( all string formated api ) correct handle `%Z` - `ANSI_STRING`. also `DbgPrint` too. can first format string and then print it, if you need exactly print to console. also not `LoadLibraryW( L"NtosKrnl.exe" );` but `GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll")` already

Comment: @RbMm: I've tested your suggestion by printing to a buffer first, then printing its contents to stdout; my conclusion is that `sprintf_s` and `swprintf_s` handle `Z` the same way as I described it in my question. (I received the exact same output except for one case: `printf` with `hZ` and a `UNICODE_STRING` included `'\0'` characters, so the it was truncated after the first one, "T e x t ." has become "T" but this is not caused by a difference between `printf` and `sprintf_s`.)

Comment: Under what circumstances would you not control the format string? This is starting to sound like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @zwol: It's a long story. After calling functions like `vfprintf`, the contents of the `va_list` become indeterminate according to the C standards. So I would like to create my own version that accepts a `va_list*` instead. This function could be used to do some custom processing with format strings. I know that `Z` is rarely used but I would like it prepare for every possibility.

Comment: from which dll you call `sprintf_s / swprintf_s` ? i use ntdll.dll and msvsrt.dll. in bot this case it correct handle `%Z` format with ansi_string

Comment: Sounds like the solution to your problem is [`va_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_copy).

Comment: @RbMm: I have a Microsoft Developer Studio 2022 project where the "Runtime Library" is setting equals "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)". The point is, however, that - after the change of the documentation - you cannot say which behavior is the correct one. Both can be depending on the version of the CRT. And I don't see why sprintf_s would differ from printf in this respect, since their documentation links to the same page regarding the format specifiers.

Comment: @IInspectable: `va_copy` is part of my solution but is not enough because I need to track which arguments printf consumed.

Comment: sprintf_s / swprintf_s  implemented in many different modules. and may be some implementation is different. i say that implementations inside ntdll.dll, msvcrt.dll and ntoskrnl.exe always correct handle %Z format with ANSI_STRING

Comment: @RbMm: Right, `( ( int ( * )( char const*, ... ) ) GetProcAddress( LoadLibraryW( L"ntdll.dll" ), "sprintf_s" ) )( buffer, 1024, "out: %Z", &ansi_string );` prints it correctly (according to the old rules). I'm not sure, however, that after changing it in VS, they won't change it at other places.

Comment: ntdll/msvcrt not depend frpm VS and any crt version. this was always, how thay handle %Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the discussion of what various concrete implementations, in various DLLs, of various versions of sprintf, actually do --- is a big fat red herring.

The *real* obstacle here is that *your caller* may have provided *either* a UNICODE_STRING or an ANSI_STRING along with an unqualified %Z argument, and you have no way of knowing which.

In your shoes, I would document that unqualified %Z is not supported at all, due to historical ambiguity, and callers must use either %hZ or %wZ.  And I'd enforce that in my code: prescan the format string and bomb out if an unqualified %Z is encountered.

Comment: Thanks, I'll avoid `Z` for now. But I may need to change this later, so I posted my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think this is a quite rare situation but if anyone is interested, there are two ways to handle this question.

1. I wrote a function, `isUniversalCRunTimeLibrary` that - based on testing with `snprintf` - returns `true` if the C runtime library is successfully detected as this new universal one, and `false` otherwise (if the detection was successful but it is the old version, then the optional parameter `detectionSucceededOptional` is set to `true`; if it is set to `false`, it means that an error occurred during detection).
2. As RbMm suggested, ntdll's `sprintf_s` uses the old version: Compare `bufferA` and `bufferB` in the output. However, I'm afraid that if Microsoft changed this behavior in VS, then (assuming they use their own development product), they may change ntdll's `sprintf_s` in the future.

Here is my code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef struct _STRING {
    unsigned short lengthInBytes;
    unsigned short capacityInBytes;
    char* data;
} ANSI_STRING;

bool tryRtlInitAnsiString( ANSI_STRING* ansi_string, char const* content )
{
    HINSTANCE hModule = LoadLibraryW( L"NtosKrnl.exe" );
    assert( hModule != NULL );
    if( hModule == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }
    typedef void ( CALLBACK *RtlInitAnsiStringType )( ANSI_STRING*, char const* );
    RtlInitAnsiStringType pRtlInitAnsiString = ( RtlInitAnsiStringType ) GetProcAddress( hModule, "RtlInitAnsiString" );
    assert( pRtlInitAnsiString != NULL );
    if( pRtlInitAnsiString == NULL ) {
        return false;
    }
    pRtlInitAnsiString( ansi_string, content );
    return true;
}

bool detectUniversalCRunTimeLibrary( bool* detectionSucceeded )
{
    char const* testFormat = "%Z";
    char const testString[] = "tt";
    ANSI_STRING ansi_string;
    bool successRtlInitAnsiString = tryRtlInitAnsiString( &ansi_string, testString );
    if( !successRtlInitAnsiString ) {
        *detectionSucceeded = false;
        return false;
    }
    int errnoBefore = errno;
    errno = 0;
    int charactersWritten = snprintf( NULL, 0, testFormat, &ansi_string );
    int errnoRelevant = errno;
    errno = errnoBefore;
    bool correctOld = charactersWritten == sizeof( testString ) / sizeof( testString[ 0 ] ) - 1 && errnoRelevant == 0;
    bool correctNew = charactersWritten < 0 && errnoRelevant == EILSEQ;
    assert( correctOld || correctNew );
    *detectionSucceeded = correctOld || correctNew;
    return correctNew;
}

bool isUniversalCRunTimeLibrary( bool* detectionSucceededOptional )
{
    static bool universalCRunTimeLibrary = false;
    static bool detectionSucceeded = false;
    static bool alreadyTested = false;
    if( !alreadyTested ) {
        alreadyTested = true;
        universalCRunTimeLibrary = detectUniversalCRunTimeLibrary( &detectionSucceeded );
    }
    if( detectionSucceededOptional != NULL ) {
        *detectionSucceededOptional = detectionSucceeded;
    }
    return universalCRunTimeLibrary;
}

int main()
{
    bool detectionSucceeded = false;
    bool universalCRunTimeLibrary = isUniversalCRunTimeLibrary( &detectionSucceeded );
    printf( "universalCRunTimeLibrary: %d (detectionSucceeded: %d)\n", universalCRunTimeLibrary, detectionSucceeded );

    char const* testFormat = "%Z";
    char const testString[] = "tt";
    ANSI_STRING ansi_string;
    bool successRtlInitAnsiString = tryRtlInitAnsiString( &ansi_string, testString );
    if( !successRtlInitAnsiString ) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char bufferA[ 256 ] = "";
    errno = 0;
    int writtenA = sprintf_s( bufferA, sizeof( bufferA ) / sizeof( bufferA[ 0 ] ), testFormat, &ansi_string );
    int errnoA = errno;
    printf( "bufferA = \"%s\", writtenA = %d, errnoA = %d\n", bufferA, writtenA, errnoA );

    HINSTANCE hModuleNtdll = LoadLibraryW( L"ntdll.dll" );
    assert( hModuleNtdll != NULL );
    if( hModuleNtdll == NULL ) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    typedef int ( *sprintf_sType )( char const*, ... );
    sprintf_sType psprintf_s = ( sprintf_sType ) GetProcAddress( hModuleNtdll, "sprintf_s" );
    assert( psprintf_s != NULL );
    if( psprintf_s == NULL ) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char bufferB[ 256 ] = "";
    errno = 0;
    int writtenB = psprintf_s( bufferB, sizeof( bufferB ) / sizeof( bufferB[ 0 ] ), testFormat, &ansi_string );
    int errnoB = errno;
    printf( "bufferB = \"%s\", writtenB = %d, errnoB = %d\n", bufferB, writtenB, errnoB );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output:

```
universalCRunTimeLibrary: 1 (detectionSucceeded: 1)
bufferA = "", writtenA = -1, errnoA = 42
bufferB = "tt", writtenB = 2, errnoB = 0
```